# (Android) Want: dead battery -> plug in phone -> phone auto ON

Tags: android, battery

Here's the scenario:

Phone's battery is dead.
You go to plug in the phone.
From here, I'd like the phone to automatically turn itself ON once it detects a power source.

What's the best way to do this? Is there an android solution or would this take a custom ROM or something lower-level?

Answer (score 3):

This could be done only on hardware level. No software could power up phone if it is truly off - not in sleep or any other passive state.